# Electrical Outlets not working after pressure washing my house

Tags: electrical

I just had my house pressure washed and painted and after the power washing the power to half of my garage isn't working. We had an electrician come look and everything looked fine. He told us to "wait a few days" for things to dry out. It's been a week and still nothing. Help.

Comment: Is your garage fed by a GFCI circuit or is there a panel in the garage. I would have been looking for a GFCI breaker or outlet that was tripped. For an “electrician” to wait a few days I would like to see the box of Crackerjacks he got his license out of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably one GFCI protected receptacle outside got water in it. This could trip a GFCI. If it is a GFCI that has tripped, then some GFCI receptacle or GFCI breaker should be in the tripped state. The GFCI receptacle itself may be inside and not gotten wet, but if some outside receptacle on the load side of a GFCI gets wet it can trip the dry GFCI.

You can dry these out by removing just the cover plate of any outside receptacles that could have gotten wetted and blowing dry air such as a hair dryer on low heat high fan. Better might be a leaf blower or shop vac exhaust. Even any vac on suction might work.